# Why is this giving me a linker error? (random number generation using <random>)

Tags: c++, random, linker

NOTE: coord is a std::pair

```
   class Random
{
public:
    Random()
    {
        gen.seed(rd());
    };
    coord rnd_coord(int x, int y)
    {
        std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist_x(0, x - 1);
        std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist_y(0, y - 1);
        coord temp;
        temp.first = dist_x(gen);
        temp.second = dist_y(gen);
        return temp;
    }
private:
    static std::random_device rd;
    static std::mt19937 gen;
};
```

Then in main.cpp

```
int x;
Random R;
coord C;
C = R.rnd_coord(10, 10);
std::cout << C.first << ", " << C.second << std::endl;
std::cin >> x;

return 0;
```

Im doing some tests with  but I'm having a lot of issues with it :(, tbh I havent programmed in a while. Anyway, I want to make a helper function that will return random coordinates in the specified bounds, said function is in "snake_utility.h", but as it was giving me errors i put it in a class, and now I get linker errors:

> Error 1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static
>   class std::random_device Random::rd"
>   (?rd@Random@@0Vrandom_device@std@@A)  C:\Users\Reethok\Desktop\C++\Pet
>   Projects\Snake\Snake\main.obj Snake Error 2   error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol "private: static class
>   std::mersenne_twister_engine
>   Random::gen"
>   (?gen@Random@@0V?$mersenne_twister_engine@I$0CA@$0CHA@$0BIN@$0BP@$0JJAILANP@$0L@$0PPPPPPPP@$06$0JNCMFGIA@$0P@$0OPMGAAAA@$0BC@$0GMAHIJGF@@std@@A)  C:\Users\Reethok\Desktop\C++\Pet
>   Projects\Snake\Snake\main.obj Snake Error 3   error LNK1120: 2
>   unresolved externals  C:\Users\Reethok\Desktop\C++\Pet
>   Projects\Snake\Debug\Snake.exe    1   1   Snake

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

Non-`static` member variables of a class are constructed when you construct an instance of the class. The `static` member variables, on the other hand, are same for all instances of the class. They need to be defined explicitly.

You need to define the `static` member variables in the enclosing namespace. Add

```
std::random_device Random::rd;
std::mt19937 Random::gen;
```

in a .cpp file.